# Removing certain entries from start menu on server 2019

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2019

I've been trying to find a method to remove entries from the start menu. I've found a GPO that removes all the entries, which is not what I want. I've found that some shortcuts can be removed by simply deleting .lnk files from `%appdata%/local/microsoft/windows/startmenu`. On Server2019 however, there are also entries that do not have a .lnk file such as settings, windows-security or search.

I've found some suggestions which removed the search entry but that affected also the general search functionality of windows, which is not what I want.

It can't be impossible, can it? Microsoft forums do not really help any further.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/windows-10-start-layout-options-and-policies?redirectedfrom=MSDN#start-options

Comment: @joeqwerty I am familiar with that page but that doesn't say anything about the list of programs :/

Answer (score 0):

This answer maybe comes late, but there is a way to just remove 1 of the options:
do regedit and go to: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Start\HideShutDown
(this is for the shutdown button)
Set "value" to 1 to remove the shutdown button.

You also find the other buttons - HideRestart, HideSleep, ...

[Regedit to hide several options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOKJ2.png)